# Python, selenium - "is not reachable by keyboard", не даёт передать текст в input

Tags: python, html, selenium

Получаю img с каптчей на сайте, обрабатываю, получаю разгаданную каптчу, дальше пытаюсь её вставить в input поле на сайте, но получаю ошибку, предполагаю что поле защищено как то, руками Ctrl+V не работает, вставляется только первый символ, как можно решить данную проблему?

html поле для ввода

```
<input class="capchaInput" tabindex="-1" type="text" name="code" autocomplete="off" id="code" maxlength="6" onkeyup="change_tr();">
```

Запускаю селениум

```
code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="code"]')  # Нахожу input на странице
code.send_keys(text_ready)  # Передаю разгаданный текст капчи
```

И получаю ошибку

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="code" class="getjob_capchaInput" name="code" type="text"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Comment: Леонид, я прекрасно понимаю вашу проблему, сам с нею столкнулся. Как можно с вами связаться? Мне интересно, как вы это решили. )

Comment: @SEMUL наверное уже позно) Но оказалось всё просто, по этому полю надо сначала кликнуть
-- code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="code"]') ;
-- code.click() ;
-- code.send_keys(text_ready) ;