# Имитация нажатия клавиши в активном окне

Tags: java, веб-программирование, selenium, бот

Пишу бота для одного сайта.

У меня точно такая же проблема, как в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1445517/499483) вопросе.

Мне важно передать строку в поле `input`, однако через `selenium` так не получилось. Я попробовал класс `Robot`, но проблема в том, что, когда объект класса `Robot` инициализируется, выскакивает новое окно и все дальнейшие действия акцентируются на нем.

Есть ли альтернативные методы в арсенале `java` или придётся подключать `python`-скрипт?

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно. Опишите какие задачи Вы преследуете, какие имеются требования, что пробовали и почему не подходит. Какая задача у "бота"?

Comment: У меня точно такая же проблема, как в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1445517/499483. Мне важно передать строку в input поле, однако через selenium так не получилось, я попробовал класс Robot, но проблема в том, что, когда объект класса Robot инициализируются, выскакивает новое окно и все дальнейшие действия акцентируются на нем. Есть ли альтернативные методы в арсенале java или придется подключать питоновский скрипт?

Comment: [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev) не пробовали? Есть [статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/341348), да и в целом информации по нему много. Может даже и в headless режиме выполняться и полностью имитировать действия пользователя.